# Change the contents of an iframe dynamically

Tags: html, iframe

I was wondering if there is any way form me to change the contents of an iframe dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `src` of the iframe to new URL.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your iframe is named "frame" (`<iframe name="frame">`)

```
function loadIframe(url)
{
      document.all.frame.src=url;
      document.all.frame.style.visibility="visible";
}
```

This allows you to load an URL into there.

If you want to write with javascript into it, you can try

```
document.all.frame.write("...");
```

But I don't know if it does work like this, I only know the URL part. Probably does not work, because the iframe is what it is, a frame which displays another document - you could try having a javascript in there that writes what you want. :)